# What Is Juju and Charm Store

Tags: juju

I want answers for below questions.

- What is Juju? How To Work with it ?
- What does Charm means?
- Is ubuntu Server edition is required for use Juju ? or Desktop edition can Run?
- Any one have some reference links for ebooks or something like that, can help ?

any help are appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: If Juju Docs helped you understand them, I would request you to please post your understanding as an Answer - quote the relevant parts of the documentation which helped you understand the concepts. (I believe some of your questions are duplicates of already asked questions on Ask Ubuntu - but don't worry about them). Juju is relatively very new and we do not have much resources here on Ask Ubuntu. Making an answer yourself would do no harm.